# Symmetric dictionary where d[a][b] == d[b][a]

Tags: python, inheritance, dictionary

I have an algorithm in python which creates measures for pairs of values, where `m(v1, v2) == m(v2, v1)` (i.e. it is symmetric). I had the idea to write a dictionary of dictionaries where these values are stored in a memory-efficient way, so that they can easily be retrieved with keys in any order. I like to inherit from things, and ideally, I'd love to write a `symmetric_dict` where `s_d[v1][v2]` always equals `s_d[v2][v1]`, probably by checking which of the v's is larger according to some kind of ordering relation and then switching them around so that the smaller element one is always mentioned first. i.e. when calling `s_d[5][2] = 4`, the dict of dicts will turn them around so that they are in fact stored as `s_d[2][5] = 4`, and the same for retrieval of the data.
I'm also very open for a better data structure, but I'd prefer an implementation with "is-a" relationship to something which just uses a dict and preprocesses some function arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a slightly different approach that looks promising. Although the `SymDict` class isn't a `dict` subclass, it mostly behaves like one, and there's only a single private dictionary involved. I think one interesting feature is that fact that it preserves the natural `[][]` lookup syntax you seemed to want.

```
class SymDict(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwrds):
        self._mapping = _SubSymDict(*args, **kwrds)
    def __getitem__(self, key1):
        self._mapping.set_key1(key1)
        return self._mapping
    def __setitem__(self, key1, value):
        raise NotImplementedError
    def __str__(self):
        return '_mapping: ' + self._mapping.__str__()
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self._mapping, name)

class _SubSymDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwrds):
        dict.__init__(self, *args, **kwrds)
    def set_key1(self, key1):
        self.key1 = key1
    def __getitem__(self, key2):
        return dict.__getitem__(self, frozenset((self.key1, key2)))
    def __setitem__(self, key2, value):
        dict.__setitem__(self, frozenset((self.key1, key2)), value)

symdict = SymDict()
symdict[2][4] = 24
symdict[4][2] = 42

print 'symdict[2][4]:', symdict[2][4]
# symdict[2][4]: 42
print 'symdict[4][2]:', symdict[4][2]
# symdict[4][2]: 42
print 'symdict:', symdict
# symdict: _mapping: {frozenset([2, 4]): 42}

print symdict.keys()
# [frozenset([2, 4])]
```

Answer (score 11):

You could use a [`frozenset`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) as the key for your dict:

```
>>> s_d = {}
>>> s_d[frozenset([5,2])] = 4
>>> s_d[frozenset([2,5])]
4
```

It would be fairly straightforward to write a subclass of `dict` that took iterables as key arguments and then turned then into a `frozenset` when storing values:

```
class SymDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return dict.__getitem__(self, frozenset(key))

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        dict.__setitem__(self, frozenset(key), value)
```

Which gives you:

```
>>> s_d = SymDict()
>>> s_d[5,2] = 4
>>> s_d[2,5]
4
```

Comment: I certainly like that idea! I'd still like to get rid of the redundancy, so that no first value has to be saved twice or can accidentally be saved twice...

Answer (score 3):

Doing it with nested indexing as shown will be extremely difficult. It's better to use a tuple as the key instead. That way the tuple can be sorted and an encapsulated `dict` can be accessed for the value.

```
d[2, 5] = 4
print d[5, 2]
```

Comment: I thought about that, but the values might be very complicated structures, so tuples will always be extremely redundant for the first element (because (v1, v2) and (v1, v3) will have two copies of v1, if I don't introduce a yet new structure to store pointers to all v's...) I think that makes it rather inelegant.

Comment: Probably I'll go for that version if the other is so difficult ... which member function must I override to sort a tuple given in the [ ] operator before I save it into the parent dict?

Comment: You would have to override the `__getitem__()`, `__setitem__()`, and `__delitem__()` methods. http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__

Comment: @Felix Alejandro Dombek: Python doesn't copy unless you force it. (v1, v2) and (v1, v3) will share the same v1. Also, creating tuples is about as efficient as it gets.

Comment: Hi ... what I meant was: for each tuple (v1, vn) to (v1, vm), there is a different tuple stored in the dict, that means that the pointer to v1 is stored m-n times and also all tuple metadata (whatever it is, i don't think that a python 2-tuple only occupies the raw 8 bytes for 2 pointers) is stored n-m times. That is probably usually not a problem, but to write it as clean as possible (for large n-m) my idea is to store the pointer to v1 once and just once in the first dict, and a pointer to the second dict which in turn hold only the pointers to m-n ... I don't know if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 2):

Just as an alternative to Dave Webb's frozenset, why not do a SymDict like the following:

```
class SymDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return dict.__getitem__(self, key if key[0] < key[1] else (key[1],key[0]))

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        dict.__setitem__(self, key if key[0] < key[1] else (key[1],key[0]), value)
```

From a quick test, this is more than 10% faster for getting and setting items than using a frozenset. Anyway, just another idea. However, it is less adaptable than the frozenset as it is really only set up to be used with tuples of length 2. As far as I can tell from the OP, that doesn't seem to be an issue here.

Answer (score 2):

Improving on Justin Peel's solution, you need to add `__delitem__` and `__contains__` methods for a few more dictionary operations to work.  So, for completeness,

```
class SymDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return dict.__getitem__(self, key if key[0] < key[1] else (key[1],key[0]))

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        dict.__setitem__(self, key if key[0] < key[1] else (key[1],key[0]), value)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        return dict.__delitem__(self, key if key[0] < key[1] else (key[1],key[0]))

    def __contains__(self, key):
        return dict.__contains__(self, key if key[0] < key[1] else (key[1],key[0]))
```

So then

```
>>> s_d = SymDict()
>>> s_d[2,5] = 4
>>> s_d[5,2]
4
>>> (5,2) in s_d
True
>>> del s_d[5,2]
>>> s_d
{}
```

I'm not sure, though, whether that covers all the bases, but it was good enough for my own code.

Answer (score 1):

An obvious alternative is to use a `(v1,v2)` tuple as the key into a single standard `dict`, and insert both `(v1,v2)` and `(v2,v1)` into the dictionary, making them *refer to the same object* on the right-hand side.

Answer (score 1):

I'd extract the function for more readability(for patvarilly answer)

```
class SymDict(dict):
def __getitem__(self, key):
    return dict.__getitem__(self, self.symm(key))

def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    dict.__setitem__(self, self.symm(key), value)

def __delitem__(self, key):
    return dict.__delitem__(self, self.symm(key))

def __contains__(self, key):
    return dict.__contains__(self, self.symm(key))


@staticmethod
def symm(key):
    return key if key[0] < key[1] else (key[1], key[0]).
```