# Look up a tuple in a python dictionary matching (x,y) or (y,x)

Tags: python

I've a dictionary with a `(x,y)` key, where `(x,y)` means the same as `(y,x)`, How should I do this ?

I can do:

```
>>> d = {(1,2): "foo"}
>>> i = d.get(2,1)
>>> if i is None:
...     i = d.get((1,2))
...
>>> i
'foo'
```

Is there a better way of doing this, so `d.get((2,1))` would match the key `(1,2)` directly ?
ideally i'd want to insert e.g. `(2,1)` and not have it be distinct from the `(1,2)` key as well.

Comment: What happens if both exist?  You should normalize your keys, so there's only one representation for any particular key.

Comment: @Glenn Maynard How would I best normalize this ? I get external input in the form of an x,y pair and I need to relate that to the same value for input x,y and y,x.

Comment: A very similar question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368423/python-symmetric-dictionary-where-dab-dba/4370725#4370725

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use frozensets rather than tuples.

```
d = {frozenset((1,2)): "foo"}
print d.get(frozenset((2,1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need your own datatype.  Something that return the same value for `__hash__` for `(1, 2)` and `(2, 1)`.

But why do you want to do this?  Do you want a set rather than a tuple?  That would look something like:

```
d = {}
d[frozenset((1, 2))] = 'something'
s = frozenset((2,1))
if s in d:
    print '(2, 1) is in the dict'
else:
    print 'not found'
```

Note that it must be a `frozenset`, because dict keys must be immutable.

Comment: +1 to using sets. Although you need a `frozenset` to use as a dictionary key.

Answer (score 1):

```
def normalise_input_pair(x, y):
    return x, y if x <= y else y, x
```

Memory usage may be a consideration; how many of these do you have?

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(frozenset((1,2)))
116
>>> sys.getsizeof((1,2))
36
>>>
```

Comment: This might probably match more what I need (later on atleast) - but I'll accept btilly' answer as that is a more direct answer to the question

Comment: @Anonym: please enlighten us as to why `frozenset((x, y))` is a more direct answer than `normalise_input_pair(x, y)` to "How should I do this"?